# LINQ and EF6: The context cannot be used while the model is being created

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an MVC 5 Application with EF6, and I tried my first LINQ query in a SignalR Hub.
It runs when I click on a button on a Test view page.

But I get an exception at the query:

[image: LINQ fail]

This query is my first individual code action in the MVC5 template with individual User Accounts by the template. I only created the model classes before.

If it helps: The context I'm using is the template `ApplicationDbContext:IdentityContext<ApplicationUser>`

My "OnModelCreating" method looks like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Player>()
            .HasMany(m => m.MilitaryAccess)
            .WithMany();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Player>()
            .HasMany(m => m.FactionRelationship)
            .WithMany();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You think multiple threads are the problem, yet you don't show any code that is utilizing multiple threads.

Comment: Where is OnModelCreating run?

Comment: yeah well I "think", I don't have any experience how MVC/EF works. I just created a few model classes. And the rest is still from the template. The code shown above is the first individual code action from me.

Comment: @PeterSmith It runs inside the mentioned "ApplicationDbContext" class.

Comment: The error is sort of self explanatory really, you are attempting to context before it's actually been constructed. My guess is your code is running *before* or *during* the `OnModelCreating` event is triggered - use the debugger and put a breakpoint at each section of code, you want to hit the `OnModelCreating` before you hit the `GetDBData` call, if you don't then that's your problem. Where exactly is `GetDBData` called? That's most the source of the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this and see if it helps

```
int result = -1;
using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    var battles = context.Battles.Single(o =>o.BattleId == 1);
    result = battles.Round;
}
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem with EF6.1.1 and my solution to the problem was quite simple...

Change:

```
protected ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
```

To:

```
protected ApplicationDbContext Db {get; set;}

public TestHub()
{
  Db = new ApplicationDbContext();
}
```

But if you don't like this way, you can also use the LazySingleton Pattern approach.

Happy coding!